# Assign first word of each line to key in dictionary

Tags: python, function, numpy, dictionary

So I have a problem on a homework assignment that asks for a text file to be used to create a dictionary containing keys as students names and corresponding values as NumPy 1-dimensional Matrixes.

The text file would be formatted as follows:

```
John 23 53 54 56 58    
Jane 89 54 56 76 93    
Marie-Claire 56 68 76 86 92
```

All names are one word or a hyphened name and all students have the same number of grades on their line of the file. The problem is I can't figure out how to use just the first word (the name) of each line in the text file to be the key. This was my attempt:

```
def student_grade(filename):
    with open('filename','r') as file:
        Grade_Dict = {}
        for line in file:
            words = line.split(' ')
            Grade_Dict[words[0]]= np.array(words[1:])
```

note: the problem asks for the dictionary to be made and the file to be read within a function.

I'm just confused on how to test if I got any of this code correct or not.

Comment: What's wrong with this again? If you need help testing it, just run it through the examples you gave us.

Answer (score 1):

You are very close.  A couple of small changes:

#### Code:

```
def student_grade(filename):
    with open(filename, 'rU') as file:
        grade_dict = {}
        for line in file:
            name = line.strip().split(' ')
            grade_dict[name[0]] = np.array(name[1:])
    return grade_dict
```

The filename passed to `open()` is a variable, not a string so `filename` not `"filename"`.

#### Test Code:

```
print(student_grade('file1'))
```

#### Results:

```
{'John': array(['23', '53', '54', '56', '58'], dtype='<U2'), 
 'Jane': array(['89', '54', '56', '76', '93'], dtype='<U2'), 
 'Marie-Claire': array(['56', '68', '76', '86', '92'], dtype='<U2')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this :

```
grade={}
with open('file.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        data=line.split()
        grade[data[0]]=np.array(list(map(int,data[1:])))
print(grade)
```

output:

```
{'Marie-Claire': array([56, 68, 76, 86, 92]), 'Jane': array([89, 54, 56, 76, 93]), 'John': array([23, 53, 54, 56, 58])}
```

if you don't want numbers in int then:

```
grade={}
with open('file.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        data=line.split()
        grade[data[0]]=np.array(data[1:])
print(grade)
```